# JS to detect browser width and height works in Chrome & Safari but not IE9 or FF9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

Is there any reason why this code would work in Safari and Chrome but not IE or FF?

JS

```
function load(){
    w.value = window.outerWidth;
    h.value = window.outerHeight;
}
```

HTML

```
<input name="h" id="h" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="w" id="w" type="hidden" value="" />
```

[Click here for the entire page's source code](http://pastebin.com/dYx0ejCh)

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Edit: I figured out what was wrong.  The following had to be added to the load function

```
var width = document.getElementById("w");
var height = document.getElementById("h");
width.value = window.outerWidth;
height.value = window.outerHeight;
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What is it doing, what is it not doing, what errors are being thrown, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Internet Explorer use different properties to store the window size. Into Internet Explorer clientWidth/Height is inner window size (subtract the pixels used by scroll bar, menu etc) so try

```
function load(){
  if(window.outerHeight){
      w.value = window.outerWidth;
      h.value = window.outerHeight;
  }
  else {
      w.value = document.body.clientWidth;
      h.value = document.body.clientHeight; 
  }
}
```

Comment: You might as well use jQuery's `.width()`/`.height()`, the code used here is the same that you are already including with jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery methods which support almost all the browsers.

```
function load(){
    w.value = $(window).width();
    h.value = $(window).height();
}
```

Reference: [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/), [height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using jQuery then I suggest using `.width()` and `.height()` because they will function properly cross-browser. `window.outerWidth` is not supported in IE 8 and below.

Here are some good docs for `window.outerWidth`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.outerWidth

Using `.width()` and `.height()` will return a unit-less number (that is in pixels), if you want to get the exact height/width set (including `px` or `em`) then you can use `.css('width')` and `.css('height')`.

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314988/why-is-the-value-of-height-in-chrome-different-with-safari