# IE11 has different clientWidth and clientHeight than all other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I've created a little component that shows a thumbnail with some buttons that show on hover, nothing fancy.  It works just fine in all browsers EXCEPT IE11, because it hates me.  I've been searching everywhere for an answer and can't seem to figure it out.

This component takes an image, shrinks it so that it fits either width or height-wise within the available container (which one depends if it's a landscape or portrait photo), and then centers the image horizontally and vertically within the container.

I've tried using jquery to get the width, hoping that would normalize it between browsers, I've tried style refactoring, and even refactored the way my components work (though this one was overdue for a refactor anyways).

On image load, the loadImage event fires, and in the first few lines of the method, I'm seeing the issue

```
loadImage: function (el) {
                if (!el) {
                    return;
                }

                var width = el.naturalWidth;
                var height = el.naturalHeight;
                var parentWidth = el.parentElement.clientWidth;
                var parentHeight = el.parentElement.clientHeight;
                ...
}
```

el.parentElement.clientWidth is 100% of the container width, rather than being the size of the image!

This is using vue js, but here's the html

```
<div class='thumbnail-container'>
        <img class='item-thumbnail' ref='imgEl'
             :src='imageSource'
             :style='{ width: thumbnailWidth,
                                height: thumbnailHeight,
                                "margin-left": thumbnailMarginLeft,
                                "margin-top": thumbnailMarginTop }'
             @load='imgLoaded' />
    </div>
```

Everything is calculating correctly, the issue is that thumbnail-container is the full width of the column its in in IE11, but only the size of the img tag within it in chrome, so the height and width get thrown off.

These are the styles on thumbnail-container

```
.thumbnail-container {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Thumbnail container's parent's styling:

```
.modules-widget-thumbnail-body .modules-widget-thumbnail-cont {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
```

The expected result is for the img tag to dictate the size of thumbnail container, not the other way around.  This set up works in chrome, firefox, and edge, but not IE11.  Does anyone have any ideas what's wrong with my styling?

Note: Not sure why this is marked as a duplicate, the link there clearly specifies browser window size being incorrect, this is for an element size being incorrect, and, as stated, I've already tried using the jquery width/height methods with no change

Looks like it's related to flex though, removing .module.widget's display: flex makes them display the same, but is there any way to mimic what chrome is doing in IE?

```js
function imgLoaded(e) {
  console.log("Width: " + e.target.parentElement.clientWidth + " Height: " + e.target.parentElement.clientHeight);
}
```

```css
.module.widget .module-body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.modules-widget-thumbnail-body {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.modules-widget-thumbnail-body .modules-widget-thumbnail-cont {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.thumbnail-container[data-v-537a556c] {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modules-widget-thumbnail-body .modules-widget-thumbnail-cont img {
    align-self: center;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.module.widget {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #D9DFE1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="modules-widget-thumbnail module widget"> 
  <div class="modules-widget-thumbnail-body module-body" style="height: 400px;">
    <div id="modules-widget-thumbnail-thumbnail-1570032551907" class="modules-widget-thumbnail-cont thumbnail-view">
      <div data-v-537a556c="" class="thumbnail-container" style="position: relative;">
        <img data-v-537a556c="" src="https://i.imgur.com/UBPVhan.jpg" onload="imgLoaded(event)" class="item-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS to detect browser width and height works in Chrome & Safari but not IE9 or FF9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182811/js-to-detect-browser-width-and-height-works-in-chrome-safari-but-not-ie9-or-ff)

Comment: Did you try to check the applied styles using developer tools? generally Flex causes some issues while using it in Internet Explorer. you can check and let us know about the results. It can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The link there does not solve the issue, I've already used jquery's width() and height(), the numbers are different in IE.

The styles in dev tools appear to be the same, though

Comment: I've removed flex from the equation entirely and have the same issue - thumbnail-container is stretching its content rather than being the same size as its content

Comment: It's quite hard to debug an issue we can't reproduce. Can you reproduce the rendered HTML, JS, and CSS into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) so that we can see the problem "in action"?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've updated the original question with a stack snippet and, in doing so, came across a sneaky display flex in a parent container.  Removing that makes both chrome and IE display the same, the problem is that it looks good the way it is in chrome, and I was hoping to get IE to mimic that behavior, rather than uglifying both.  Any ideas on how to make IE respect the flex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of this comment section https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/239

Apparently IE11 uses the default align-items setting, which is stretch.  Explicitly setting the following style fixes it

```
.modules-widget-thumbnail {
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You just saved me a lot of time! :)