# why is the value of height() in chrome different with safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, height, materialize

My script like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: _url,
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result) {
        ...
    }
}).done(function () {
    for(var i=0;i<7;i++) {
        this["td"+i] = $('#bodychel-' + coachId + clubId + ' table tbody td:eq(' + (i) + ')').height();
        $('#bodychel-' + coachId + clubId + ' table thead th:eq(' + (i) + ')').css({ height: this["td"+i] });
    }
});
```

If I `console.log(this["td"+i]);`, the result is different between chrome and safari. the result of chrome is true

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: the result of chrome is true? so, in safari it's false? Or did you mean correct? If so, what is the value in Chrome, what is it in Safari, and can you show enough HTML so that we can see this difference for ourselves

Comment: @Bravo Yes, the result of chrome is true. If I `console.log(this["td"+i]);` in the chrome, the result : 51.8182. But in the safari is 42.

Comment: add reset css to your css file

Comment: so you're using the word "true" to mean "correct" - just to clarify

Comment: @MNNTNK What do you mean?

Comment: @Bravo Yes of course

Comment: @SuccessMan copy styles from this page to your main css file on top : https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: If you inspect the element, it's ancestors and descendants, in each of those browsers, can you see where the difference is coming from - it may well be a default font size making the difference

Comment: @MNNTNK it seems strange. it is not a solution

Comment: @Bravo I'm still confused. I need a spesific answer

Comment: you need to show enough in your question to be able to get an answer - we can't debug for you since you've shown zero HTML and CSS ... have you even looked at the elements using inspect element as per my previous comment

Comment: @SuccessMan Can you provide a fiddle for this? Or at least HTML and CSS code for the same